# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join') Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

im trying to create my discord music bot, but when i run it. It cannot join my voiceChannel, returning this error: channel_info.channelId.join is not a function. Below, my code:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const bot = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILDS", "GUILD_MESSAGES"] });
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
const botToken = 'mytoken';

bot.login(botToken);
    bot.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('to olain');
});

bot.on('message', msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) {
        return;
    }

    if (msg.content.toLowerCase().startsWith(';p')) {

        const channel_info = msg.member.guild.voiceStates.cache.find(user => user.id == msg.author.id);

        if (channel_info.channelId == null) {
            return console.log('Canal não encontrado!');
        }
        console.log('Canal encontrado');

        channel_info.channelId.join().then(connection => {
                const stream = ytdl('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BxmMGnvvDCo', {         filter: 'audioonly' });

            const DJ = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
            DJ.on('end', end => {
                channel_info.channelId.leave();
                });
            })
            .catch(console.error);
    }
});
```

Comment: is `channel_info.channelId` an array? Because you can only use [`.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) on arrays or an array-like object

Comment: I think you are trying to join a vc. This is not the right way. If you are on v13, you'll need the `@discordjs/voice` package. If you are on v12, make sure it is the channel object. Not the id.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues in this code. Even if we fix some of these issues, this code will still not work due to differences between discord.js v12 and v13. Let's get started.

**Issue #1**

This is not one of the core issues causing your code to not work, but it's something useful to consider. You are doing this to get the voice state of the message author:

```js
msg.member.guild.voiceStates.cache.find(user => user.id == msg.author.id);
```

When you could easily do the exact same thing in a much shorter, less-likely-to-produce-errors way:

```js
msg.member.voice;
```

**Issue #2**

Now this *is* a core issue causing your code to not work. In fact, it is causing the error in your question. You are trying to do:

```js
channel_info.channelId.join();
```

That does not make sense. You are trying to join a channel ID? `channelId` is just a String of numbers like so: `"719051328038633544"`. You can't "join" that String of numbers. You want to join the actual [channel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) that the member is in, like so:

```js
channel_info.channel.join();
```

**Issue #3**

Based on how you are using a `channelId` property instead of `channelID`, I assume you are on discord.js v13. Voice channels do not have a `.join()` method on v13; in fact, discord.js v13 has no support for joining or playing audio in voice channels. You must install the [discord.js/voice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@discordjs/voice) package in order to join a voice channel in discord.js v13. This is critical. Even if you fix the above two issues, you must solve this third issue or your code will not work (unless you downgrade to discord.js v12).

Comment: Got it! Ive done a downgrade to discord.js v12 to fix that problem. And finally i got it! Ty